# Nginx snippet nested location block

Tags: nginx

I want to create a snippet with a location block "/ErrorPages/" which can be nested in any other location block using include, but the requirement for nested locations prevents this. I'm using this to implement custom error pages which can be selectively included for each location.

error-pages.conf:

```
proxy_intercept_errors on;

error_page 400 /ErrorPages/HTTP400.html;

location /ErrorPages/ {
    alias /var/www/html/ErrorPages/;
    internal;
}
```

site.conf

```
server {
    ...
    location /app/ {
        include /etc/nginx/snippets/error-pages.conf;
        proxy_pass ...;
        proxy_redirect default; 
    }
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass ...;
        proxy_redirect default;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make this work using only one include?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't, the solution is what you've already implemented, to create a separate configuration file, named `error-pages.conf`, with the error handling configuration, and then include it in each server block or location block as necessary. Perhaps you could improve it like this:

#### error-pages.conf:

```
# Error handling configuration
error_page 404 /ErrorPages/404.html;
error_page 500 502 503 504 /ErrorPages/5xx.html;
error_page 403 /ErrorPages/403.html;

location ^~ /ErrorPages/ {
    alias /var/www/html/ErrorPages/;
    internal;
}
```